# Is it possible to serialize changes in your application configuration to your application's app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Is there a built-in mechanism for serializing changes to your `app.config` file **using built-in functions available in .NET?**

For instance, if I have a custom property set in `Executable.exe.config` that changes during runtime, I would like .NET to update the `Executable.exe.config` accordingly.

I know I could do this by creating my own serialization mechanism, but would like to know if it's possible using functionality already available in .NET by default.

Comment: Look at using `XPATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.

There are a lot of sample on the link above or on [this article](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/) that also provides a short sample.. You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration`, and basically, you access and save the file like this:

```
// Open App.Config of executable
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Do stuff

// Save the configuration file.
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

In order to force your program to immediatly take the refreshed data, you need to refresh the section using the [ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) method

```
// Force a reload of a changed section.
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

And an important note from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/68870d68-6750-48d2-9be0-53a59de3127b/), for those that say that it doesn't work in debug mode:

> If you are running the code from the debugger (within VS) than your
>   code is actually changing the **YourAssemblyName.vshost.exe.Config** If
>   you start YourAssemblyName .exe directly from the bin\debug folder it
>   will change **YourAssemblyName.exe.Config**

Comment: Good to know, though projects I am in charge of are never configured to debug through vshost. I don't quite know what debugging through vshost does, and fairly often debugging this way causes the process to hang on exit so I just opt not to use it.